# Method name expected error when is use SynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, delegates, synchronization

I have a thread, I need to call a void like this :

```
makegraph(toplot, ite, mm_0)
```

However if I want to synchronize I should use SynchronizationContext and do :

```
SynchronizationContext mContext = null;
mContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(makegraph(toplot, ite, mm_0)),null);
```

But I have the followinf error : Method name expected .
I know that I should use delegates but I am not familiar with the syntax.

Can you help me on that please ?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? neither? First of all, `mContext` should not be null; `mContext = SynchronizationContext.Current`. Otherwise, your call to Post *looks correct* although I believe you can write `Post((state) => { makegraph(toplot, ite, mm_0); }, null)`.

Comment: I suppose `SendOrPostCallback` is [this delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.sendorpostcallback.aspx). It takes an `object` and returns `void`. Therefore, you can use a lambda arrow of this form: `mContext.Post(state => { makegraph(toplot, ite, mm_0); }, null);`. But I don't know if you want to use the object `state` in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your `mContext` variable is never set to an instance of `SynchronizationContext`, it's initialized to null.

The function [SynchronizationContext.Post()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) expects two arguments, one of type [SendOrPostCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.sendorpostcallback.aspx), and one of type object.

- If you look at the documentation for SendOrPostCallback, it is a delegate that returns void and expects a single object parameter as input.
- The `object state` parameter of the Post function is the parameter that will get passed into the delegate specified in the first paramter.

That means, you will need to make a new `makegraph` function that matches the signature of the SendOrPostCallback delegate, and then pass in all of the paramters in a single object, like so:

```
public class MakeGraphState()
{
    // These don't have to be objects, but I don't know
    // what types your toplot, ite, and mm_0 paramters are
    public object toplot { get; set; }
    public object ite { get; set; }
    public object mm_0 { get; set; }
}

public static void makegraph(object state)
{
    // Convert state to a MakeGraphState so we can get
    // all of the input paramters
    MakeGraphState myState = (MakeGraphState)object;
    makegraph(myState.toplot, myState.ite, myState.mm_0);
}
```

You could then use this code like so:

```
SynchronizationContext mContext = new SynchronizationContext();
// TODO: Initialize your SynchronizationContext
MakeGraphState state = new MakeGraphState(toplot, ite, mm_0);
mContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(makegraph), state);
```

In addition, you can just pass in your method name for the delegate as a shortcut:

```
SynchronizationContext mContext = null;
// TODO: Initialize your SynchronizationContext
MakeGraphState state = new MakeGraphState(toplot, ite, mm_0);
mContext.Post(makegraph, state);
```

For more info on delegates, see the MSDN article [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
.

Comment: Same problem as the OP, calling the Post() method on a null mContext object is going to go Kaboom!  Do consider recommending the BackgroundWorker class instead.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even look at that.  That's what I get for updating things in a hurry...  Thanks for pointing that out.